# XSLT: for-each loop gives only the first alinea

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I need to convert a xml file into a html file using XSLT. Now I've tried everything but it doesn't seem to work. I want to create a white line after every alinea.

XML code:

```
<alinea>
Willen wij daadkrachtig het economisch herstel vorm kunnen geven, dan 
is stabiel bestuur gewenst. Intensief wordt sinds de
<organisatie> Tweede Kamer</organisatie>
-verkiezingen van
<datum>9 juni</datum>
gewerkt aan de totstandkoming van een nieuw kabinet. Lopende de 
kabinetsformatie past het huidige kabinet terughoudendheid bij het doen 
van beleidsvoorstellen voor het komende jaar.
</alinea>
```

and then a lot of this tags.

XSLT code:

```
<xsl:template match="troonrede">
<xsl:for-each select="troonrede/alinea">
    <xsl:value-of select="troonrede/alinea"/><br/>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown the `troonrede` element in your XML, but assuming it is the parent of the `alinea` your template should look like this...

```
<xsl:template match="troonrede">
  <xsl:for-each select="alinea">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <br/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This is because within a template matching `troonrede` you will be then positioned on that element, and so your `xsl:for-each` can then be relative to that current node. And similarly within the `xsl:for-each`, the current node is then `alinea`, so doing `.` gets the value of the current node. (Doing `<xsl:value-of select="alinea"/>` would look for a child node of the same node, which wouldn't exist.)